# Meteor reactive collection data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I getting bookings/data by the helper:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers  ({
    getUserBookings: function() {
        _deps.depend();
        var user = Meteor.user();    
        getBookingsClient(user.emails[0]['address'], function(err, res){
            if ( err ) { console.log("Booking get error.");
            } else {
                console.log("Booking get correct.");
                Session.set('bookingResponse', res);
            }
        });    
        return Session.get('bookingResponse') || "";
    }
```

And in my template:

```
 {{#if getUserBookings}}
      {{#each getUserBookings}}
          {{bookingName}}
      {{/each}}
 {{/if}}
```

How I can make this data reactive?
I mean when I change for example `bookingName` in my mongoDB it will immediately change it on website?

---

Update:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    getBookingsClient = function (email, callback) {
        Meteor.call('getBookings', email, callback);
    };
}


if(Meteor.isServer) {
    getBookings: function (email) {
        check(email, String);
        var bookings = Bookings.find({'clientDetails.email': email}).fetch();
        return bookings;
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for getBookingsClient()?

Comment: Irrelevant. This is an implementation error. Method calls are not reactive (although they can be placed within an autorun block). This situation calls for a subscription.

Comment: @BrettMcLain updated

Comment: Your method is fundamentally incorrect. I recommend doing the official [Meteor Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) for basic usage examples.

Comment: Regular method calls or meteor method calls? It looked like a regular method call to me due to his syntax; obviously it turned out that it was a meteor method call.

Comment: Now I get it :)
Thank You all Very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish the booking information from the server and subscribe to it from the client. It might look like this:

```
// server/publications.js
Meteor.publish('bookingData', function() {
    return Bookings.find({userId: this.userId});
});

// client/template.js
Template.dashboard.helpers({
    userBookings() {
        return Bookings.find({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    }
});

Template.dashboard.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('bookingData');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer by Brendan Turner: To get reactivity in Meteor you need to use one of the defined reactive sources or implement one as shown in the docs: [Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity).

Anything that results in a Cursor (returned from database query) is reactive. To retrieve Cursors you can use the [Publish and Subscribe](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) model as shown. Publish the data you want a client to have access to, and have the code subscribe to retrieve the data.

Template Helpers are reactive computations. If they have reactive data sources, they will be reactive.